# Configuring gradle compileOptions

Tags: android, build.gradle

My project's gradle file has the following:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

What would the sourceCompatibility / targetCompatibility be if this value was not set (how can you check this)? How is it that these values can be changed? Do all android devices have Java 1.6 and 1.7 installed?

Comment: You probably don't want to check the current value.  You probably just want to set the value based on what you know about the version of the android build tools you're using, and what api level your app supports. Unfortunately these things change over time so you kinda have to stay up to date on the tools.

Answer (score 1):

`sourceCompatibility` specifies that version of the Java programming language be used to compile .java files.

Default value of `sourceCompatibility` is the version of the current JVM in use.

Default value of `targetCompatibility` is `sourceCompatibility`.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use Java 8 lambdas on Android via [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) with this config:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It sounds like product placement.

Comment: I've just pointed out how these values could be changed and for what reason.

Comment: Yes, and that didn't answer the question.

Comment: As well as your comment. Probably because the question is too ambiguous.So I don't understand your claims